# Является ли композит нодов полноценным нодом в Composite pattern?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, компоновщик

В википедии сказано:

> clients should ignore the difference between compositions of objects
>   and individual objects

Мне кажется, что пример в той же википедии на Java не соответствует данному утверждению. Метод print:

```
public void print() {
    for (Graphic graphic : childGraphics) {
        graphic.print();
    }
}
```

А вот на C# все в порядке:

```
public override void Display(int depth)
{
  Console.WriteLine(new String('-', depth) + name);

  // Recursively display child nodes
  foreach (Component component in children)
  {
    component.Display(depth + 2);
  }
}
```

Что я вижу? На Java композит отрабатывает всех своих детей и забывает о себе самом!

На C# сперва выполняется действие присущее самому себе, а потом отрабатываются дети, что правильно в моем понимании.

Я что-то не понял в шаблоне или это действительно ошибка?

Ссылка на материал: [Компоновщик (шаблон проектирования)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Паттерны ООП манипулируют интерфейсами - а не реализацией. Поэтому словосочетание "полноценный нод" надо рассматривать в том смысле, что любой внешний код может работать с композитом не зная о том что это композит.

Поэтому реализация метода print/Display совершенно не важна. Важен лишь тот факт, что этот метод есть, он работает и его можно вызвать у композита точно так же, как и у любой другой ноды.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, тут все зависит от логики, что код должен делать. Если он должен распечатать какие то значения в нодах, и если композитный нод не содержит этого значения (пример на java) то естественно, он рекурсивно пытается добраться до тех кототорые содержат. В шарпе же, печаются все ноды с указанием глубины, отсюда и выполнение стороннего кода в композитном ноде. Надеюсь я вас не запутал =)

А клиент в обоих случаях ничего не знает, он просто вызывает метод print, а что выполняется внутри, он не в курсе